# Unreadable screen- even when using Doom-one theme

Tags: themes

I am new to Doom Emacs,
I am using default theme Doom-one which for the most part is fine. The problem I have is when I open any screen after just opening Emacs such as the config files I get this type of problem [image: from the evil tutorial] (notice that whatever line I am it different that its dark)

Here is the main screen of Emacs [image: this is fine]

Side notes: I am running with Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2 but don't think this is root cause of my problem.

I am not sure how to call this screen other than that the entire screen was highlighted except for current line. I have not tweaked any themes and just used the default theme that came with Doom Emacs.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to both StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Please choose one to keep and delete the other.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for advice. My first thought was to go to StackOverflow but then discovered this forum which I think is more appropriate. I tried to delete the other post however there was already a reply post. I had to flag it for a moderator to delete the post. and I will keep in mind in the future to only post in one of the forums.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help!